# range based for loop with an auto reference to a pointer

Tags: c++, c++11

With regard to the following code I would like to have some clarification. We have an array of pointers to a class. Next we loop over the array using a range based loop. For this range based loop `auto&` is used. But next when we use the element `a` we can use the arrow operator to call a function.

This code is compiled using C++ 11.

```cpp
// Definition of an array of pointers to some class.
some_class* array[10];

// The array of pointers is set.

// Loop over the array.
for(auto& a : array) 
{
  // Call some function using the arrow operator.
  a->some_func();
}
```

Is my understanding correct that `auto& a` is a reference to a pointer? Is this not a bit over kill. Would using `auto a` not create a copy of the pointer and take up the same amount of memory?

Comment: The question is if you want to modify value of pointer of `array`. If so, you have to use `auto&`, if not, use `auto` to only read data pointed by `a` pointer.

Comment: Both have the same effect. I would not worry about copying vs referencing a pointer, it will get optimized away anyway in this case. I would worry more about the fragility of plain arrays (and the two-star nature of an array of pointers, getting dangerously close to [three-star-programming](https://web.archive.org/web/20190613103311/http://wiki.c2.com/?ThreeStarProgrammer)...).

Comment: Since references are implemented as pointers, it's virtually the same.

Comment: Thank you all for answering! It is not required to change the pointer in this case so we will drop the ampersand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code [compiles](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/AhgXOC) fine.

Nevertheless, there is not really a point using a reference here, if you don't like to change it.

Best practise here is

- Use `const auto &T` if the content shall not be changed.  The reference is important, if the type `T` of auto is large. Otherwise you will copy the object.
- Use `auto & T` if you like to change the content of the container you are iterating.

Answer (score 1):

> Is my understanding correct that auto& a is a reference to a pointer?

Yes that's correct

> Would using auto a not create a copy of the pointer and take up the same amount of memory

Think of `references` as an alias for the variable, that is, think of it as a different name.

> as for this -> not create a copy of the pointer`

A pointer is very light weight and copying a pointer is relatively cheap (that's how views are implemented, pointers to sequences). If the object underline the container you are iterating is a fundamental type or a pointer to some type, `auto` is enough. In cases where the underline object of a container is a heavy weight object, then `auto&` is a better alternative (and ofc you can add `const` qualifier if you don't want to modify it).